# How to assign a variable using firebase javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Reading the firebase doc this line:

```
database.ref('/').once('value').then(function(snapshot)
```

That is from a paragraph titled "Read data once" which I'm assuming reads in all the data from the database.

I'm just struggling to figure out how to assign data from the object that is returned to a variable in javascript.

What I want to do is populate a dropdown list with place names.

For instance if I have a field called Location in the db containing place names eg Sydney, Melbourne, Brisbane how would I get the data from the returned object and assign it a variable called place so I can then use the place variable to populate the html dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this simple code -

```
database.ref('/').once('value').then(function(snapshot){
    var list = snapshot.val();
    if(list)
    {
        for (item in list) 
        {
            itemIndex = item;
            item = list[item];
            //access your properties of the object say - item.location
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. My data is structured as follows: \n

Comment: @JeromeGoldstein - let me know if you require any input.

Answer (score 0):

You have to user 'child_added'

example:

```
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('someChild');
    dbRef.on('child_added', function(snap){
      var res = snap.val().theValueYouNeed;  
   });
```

The code above gets the specific child in your db like this:

```
someChild:{
     theValueYouNeed:"some value"
    }
```

Then you can populate your list with the values.

I hope this helps!